# Why PHP save windows-1252 text to a utf8mb4 database?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I was trying to convert `utf8` to `utf8mb4` for a php website, unfortunately, I was success on localhost but failed on test server.

localhost:

- php/5.3.29(brew install php53) or PHP/5.6.8(xampp)
- Apache/2.4.16

test server:

- PHP/5.6.14
- nginx/1.6.0

They are connecting to the same mysql database(encoding: utf8mb4, collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci).
data tables: (encoding: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci)
some data tables: (encoding: utf8mb4, collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

The php website with [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/) framework current config:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

With this config, everything is ok. When I change the config to:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8mb4';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
```

everything is ok on my localhost server but not test server.

On test server, the page text which get data from DB show `???`. I try to insert a comment with emoji from page, the comment text is ok.

I use a mysql client Sequel Pro to connect the database, I find the comment that inserted just now is incorrect encoding(windows-1252). PHP save windows-1252 text to a utf8 database.

T_T, please help me. Is that some php extends required?

Comment: What are the MySQL versions?

Comment: The MySQL version is 5.6.16

Comment: Sounds like your webapp is using an incorrect connection encoding.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/476, confirm every step, debug your values by outputting them as `bin2hex($str)` and figure out at which point they are changed how. This doesn't really contain enough information to diagnose anything specifically for you.

Comment: @deceze Thank you. I will debug it step by step~

Comment: Also do `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` to see what is in the table already.

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of _that_ thread.  This involves doing `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO utf8mb4` on each table.  It _may_ involve dealing with any indexes on `VARCHAR(255)`; let us know if you have any such.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. I try to save `haha` to db from website page and then run `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...`. Local server: `haha F09F988268616861`, test server: `ðŸ˜haha C3B0C5B8CB9CC28168616861`.

Comment: There are some mistakes at the php level, I think. Both local and test server are connecting to one database, and it works well on local server but not on test server. They have the same code and file encoding(utf-8).

Comment: You have `latin1` somewhere on the test server, probably when connecting the client to the mysql server.  So, maybe this is a dup thread.

Comment: latin1 and cp1252 are virtually the same.

Comment: By all means, please post that answer as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it.

On test server, the php use mysql extends without mysqlnd, so the charset depends on `/usr/share/mysql/charsets/` settings. If it missed `utf8mb4` defined, the `mysql_set_charset` function will failed: `2019: Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)`.

Just use `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8mb4')` instead.